# window not defined with peer.js

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peer

When I run my `node server.js` it gives me the following error:

```
/Users/Phil/Desktop/webrtc-core/node_modules/peerjs/lib/adapter.js:1
le, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTC
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Phil/Desktop/webrtc-core/node_modules/peerjs/lib/adapter.js:1:102)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Phil/Desktop/webrtc-core/node_modules/peerjs/lib/util.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Isn't window defined in the adapter.js file?

Comment: It shouldn't be defined, because in a node server app, there is no `window`. There is, however, `global` and `process`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the server, the object window dosnt exist, so you are confusing client code with server code, the nodeJs code is **server** code.

For example you can use for example, `console.log` on bot server/client, but you cannot use alert, on the `server side`, take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp), to know which `Properties and methods` belongs with the object window.